# Get Checked items in Checkbox tree-view JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

I am creating application in javaFX, Where I have used   Treeview
with CheckBoxTreeItem of String as its nodes.
 I want to get all checked item in the treeview , How do I achieve that?

Heres code :

```
private TreeView<String> treeView_businessAreas;
Set<String> businessAreas = config.getBusinessAreas();
    CheckBoxTreeItem<String> item = null;
    for (String businessArea : businessAreas) {
        item = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>(businessArea);
        root.getChildren().add(item);
    }



    treeView_businessAreas.setRoot(root);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that you need:

```
treeView_businessAreas.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().addListener(new ListChangeListener<TreeItem>() {

    @Override
    public void onChanged(Change<? extends TreeItem> change) {
        ObservableList<TreeItem<String>> allSelectedItems = (ObservableList<TreeItem<String>>) treeView_businessAreas.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
        //DO SOMETHING HERE WITH THE SELECTED ITEMS
    }

});
```

Comment: IMO it is more appropriate to get the selected items on some button action, instead of on every change of selected items.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Only the part `treeView_businessAreas.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()` is important. The rest is just for example purposes.

Comment: Still it _may_ be misleading to OP.

Comment: Thanks for response. But this only gives me the selected items in treeview.
What I want is to get list of all Checked items in tree.(Whose checkboxes are checked).